# MakeRelativeUri causes inconsistent LocalPath escaping?

Tags: c#, path, uri, relative-path

Consider the following program (tested with .NET 4.6.1):

```
var baseUri = new Uri(@"C:\test \", UriKind.Absolute);
var absolute = new Uri(@"C:\test \space .txt", UriKind.Absolute);
var relative = new Uri("space .txt", UriKind.Relative);
var combined = new Uri(baseUri, relative);

Uri extracted = baseUri.MakeRelativeUri(absolute);
var rebuilt = new Uri(baseUri, extracted);

Console.WriteLine(baseUri.LocalPath);  // Outputs C:\test \
Console.WriteLine(absolute.LocalPath); // Outputs C:\test \space .txt
Console.WriteLine(combined.LocalPath); // Outputs C:\test \space .txt
Console.WriteLine(rebuilt.LocalPath);  // Outputs C:\test \space%20.txt
```

I did not expect the result of the last line. Is this a bug or is it the normal behaviour? (note: executing the program from Mono 4.4.1 yields consistent results - no %20 in the output).

To get the result that I expected, the following workaround works. However, I don't feel comfortable using it until I know for sure whether it's a bug or not, because the behaviour may change.

```
var rebuilt = new Uri(baseUri, Uri.UnescapeDataString(extracted.ToString()));
```